# Why is the content of my ScrollView not displayed when I target Android?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, maui

I have the following very simple controltemplate:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="BarChartControlTemplate">
<Grid 
    x:Name="Part_Grid"
    BackgroundColor="LightYellow"
    ColumnDefinitions="*,auto">

    <ScrollView
        x:Name="Part_Scroller"
        BackgroundColor="ForestGreen"
        Orientation="Horizontal">

        <Grid
            x:Name="Part_Content"
            BackgroundColor="Orange"/>
    </ScrollView>
</Grid>
```

If I run my application targeting Windows, everything is fine; I have my Part_Grid displayed in light yellow, and my Part_Content in orange (Part_Scroller in green is obviously hidden by Part_Content) :

[image]

However, if I run my code targeting Android (on a physical device), my orange Part_Content doesn't appear anymore :

[image]

I tried to set an arbitrary size, without success.

Not surprisingly, if I take my Part_Content out of the ScrollView, it appears correctly.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="BarChartControlTemplate">
<Grid 
    x:Name="Part_Grid"
    BackgroundColor="LightYellow"
    ColumnDefinitions="*,auto">

    <ScrollView
        x:Name="Part_Scroller"
        BackgroundColor="ForestGreen"
        Orientation="Horizontal">

    </ScrollView>

    <Grid
        x:Name="Part_Content"
        BackgroundColor="Orange"/>
</Grid>
```

[image]

What would explain such a difference between Windows and Android in the way the ScrollView works?

**Update 1:**

The problem seems to come from the orientation of the ScrollView, because if I switch it to vertical, everything works fine on android (and on windows, of course).
Obviously, this is not what I want: I want to be able to scroll my graphic horizontally.

Comment: You've tagged with both xamarin.forms and maui. Which are you using?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I use MAUI and .net core 7. (I tagged Xamarin since the community is larger there, and the ScrollView is supposed to work the same).

Answer (score 1):

I more or less solved my problem by adding this line to my Part_Content:

```
<Grid
     x:Name="Part_Content"
     HeightRequest="{Binding Source={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=Height}"/>
```

Basically with this binding, I want the height of my control to match the current height of my control...

It makes absolutely no sense, I don't understand why it works, but for now it does the job.

**EDIT :**

An alternative (since the ScrollView seems to be bugged on android) is to use a CollectionView (which in my case will have only one Grid item -formerly Part_Content- created on the code side).

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="BarChartControlTemplate">
<Grid 
    x:Name="Part_Grid"
    ColumnDefinitions="*,auto">

    <CollectionView
        x:Name="Part_Scroller"
        ItemsLayout="HorizontalList">

        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentView Content="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

It works well on both platforms. And I can't decide which of the two solutions I found is the ugliest.

Comment: *"I tried to set an arbitrary size, without success."* You set the size **where**? A ScrollView has two different "sizes": the size it occupies on the screen, and the size of its content. Here "Height(Request)" is a chicken-and-egg problem. Scrollview wants Grid to tell it its HeightRequest. "Undefined" result (behavior can be platform-dependent). Setting a hardcoded HeightRequest on Grid "should" have worked (though you don't want a fixed height, I know). I think your first Hack works by triggering a second layout cycle, solving the chicken-and-egg problem.

Comment: I would understand this behavior if it were consistent from one orientation to another; in vertical scroll, I don't need to specify the width of the content, while in horizontal scroll it doesn't work without specifying the height of the content. 
And to answer the question, it's the content width that I tried to force, with no result (when in the end I needed to specify the content height).

Comment: FYI: One might expect "width" and "height" to behave identically. However, on mobile devices, they don't always. Especially for scrolling; content by default uses full width of screen; vertical scrolling is the norm. Content tends to be "stacked vertically" more often than "stacked horizontally"; the default is to NOT "grab" all vertical space. I don't know the exact implementation details on Android (could be either in Microsoft's layout code, or in Android's control layout defaults), so I don't know why it didn't "figure it out" on Android. But it does not surprise me in the least.